# What is cpack --config CPackSourceConfig.cmake actually doing?

Tags: cmake

[CMake Tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/#s6)

In Step 6 of the CMake tutorial, it says "To create a source distribution you would type" `cpack --config CPackSourceConfig.cmake`. I tried this command and get four tarballs: `output.tar.bz`, `output.tar.gz`, `output.tar.xz`and `output.tar.Z`.

The tarball is just a compression of the current directory. The Makefile packed contains absolute path of my current system. It means I need to run cmake again if I distribute it to other system.

So what is the point of using cpack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the point of using CPack for create source package is to not including version-control files into resulted tarball (see [CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CPack.html#variable:CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES) variable).

Also it is possible to futher modify list of files, intended for source package. E.g., one can exclude internal documentation (which is useful for developers only) but include some pre-generated files, so user doesn't require to have additional tools, like Flex/Bison, to build source package.

Though CPack (and especially its source package functionality) is poorly documented (see, e.g., [this mailing](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-January/041870.html) and [this bugreport](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=10067)), source package generation is relatively flexible.

Comment: I also find that the tarball includes previous tarball, `output.tar.gz` includes `output.tar.gz`.

Comment: Hm, are you create tarbal in the source directory? In that case this behaviour is expected - CPack just packs all files which it sees in the source directory.